# Why does jQuery Mobile hide some links?

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

In some cases, when a bog-standard link already has a class, jQuery Mobile adds style="width: 0px; height: 0px; margin: 0px;" to the element, effectively causing it to disappear.

So for example

```
<a href="/some-page" class="someClass">some text</a>
```

becomes

```
<a href="/some-page" class="someClass ui-link" style="width: 0px; height: 0px; margin: 0px;">some text</a>
```

There's nothing special about 'someClass' - does anyone know what might be causing this?

Comment: It must have javascript influence it. Can you provide your javascript code?

Comment: there isn't; and the same links look perfectly fine in desktop view